# Cannot convert Query with Subquery to Symfony Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query that does what is required

```
SELECT v.* FROM vehicle v 
WHERE v.company_id = 2 AND v.id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT h.vehicle_id
        FROM hire h
        WHERE
        h.start_date is not null and h.end_date is null
    )
```

So now I am trying to code this query in Symfony/Doctrine

I have this

```
$qb   = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$subq = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$subq   ->select('h.vehicle')
        ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Hire', 'h')
        ->andWhere('h.startDate is not null and h.endDate is null');

$qb->select('v')
        ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Vehicle', 'v')
        ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('v.id',$subq->getDQL()))
        ->andWhere('v.company = :company')
        ->setParameter('company', $company)
        ->orderBy('v.registrationNumber', 'ASC')
    ;
$t = $qb->getDQL();

return $qb;
```

As you see I tried dumping the DQL to see if that gave me any clues and here is is

```
SELECT v 
FROM AppBundle\Entity\Vehicle v 
WHERE (v.id NOT IN(SELECT h.vehicle FROM AppBundle\Entity\Hire h WHERE h.startDate is not null and h.endDate is null)) 
AND v.company = :company 
ORDER BY v.registrationNumber ASC
```

I tried converting this back to simple SQL i.e. removing the AppBundle stuff and converting the column names back to actual column name and it runs and get the right result.

But I am getting this error

> Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException:
>   [Semantical Error] line 0, col 69 near 'vehicle FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
>
> at vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php:63
>     at Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::semanticalError('line 0, col 69 near \'vehicle FROM\': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.', object(QueryException))

The 2 tables involved are

```
CREATE TABLE `hire` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `driver_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vehicle_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `corporate_hire` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_miles` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_miles` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_B8017EFC979B1AD6` (`company_id`),
  KEY `IDX_B8017EFCC3423909` (`driver_id`),
  KEY `IDX_B8017EFC545317D1` (`vehicle_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B8017EFC545317D1` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B8017EFC979B1AD6` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B8017EFCC3423909` FOREIGN KEY (`driver_id`) REFERENCES `driver` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicle` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `storage_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_manufacture` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `make` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `registration_number` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `vin` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_1B80E486979B1AD6` (`company_id`),
  KEY `IDX_1B80E4865CC5DB90` (`storage_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1B80E4865CC5DB90` FOREIGN KEY (`storage_id`) REFERENCES `storage` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1B80E486979B1AD6` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I am not sure what an `Invalid Path Expression` should be making me look for as an actual error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's working for us is (adapted to your example, so not tested):

```
$subQuery->select('IDENTITY(h.vehicle)');
$subQuery->from('AppBundle\Entity\Hire', 'h');

$dqlString = $subQuery->getQuery()->getDQL();

$query->andWhere('v.id' 'NOT IN (' . $dqlString . ')');
```

The only two differences that I see are:

1. subQuery returns IDENTITY() of h.vehicle, so only the 'identifier' (which is **id** in most cases)
2. our andWhere condition in main query is created manually - but your expression builder should work the same way.

So my assumption ist that your `$subq   ->select('h.vehicle')` doesn't return **id**s which can be used in the NOT IN condition of your main query, which might be proven by your resolved DQL `SELECT v` : this will return all fields, but you'd required **v.id** only.